# Change file upload destination to private in node type

Tags: files

I have several attachments in nodes and when I'm not logged in I can still download them.  I have figured out how to configure private uploads but I can't change them to private in my node type.  How do I fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7? Is the node visible when not logged in? Should the node be visible or not?

Comment: Several does not sound like a lot, why not set up a private file storage and re-attach the files. I have not tried such a move before and it sounds a bit messy.